# Grails 3 JSON Date serialization

Tags: json, date, grails, serialization

Ok, I know this is supposed to be easy.  My Grails 3.2.5 REST server using JsonViews needs to return dates to the client unaltered by the client timezone.  For testing, my client and server are both in eastern time, so there should be no difference anyway.  But what I see is that outgoing JSON date strings are adjusted to GMT, so they get 5 hours added onto them.

I can defeat this adjustment for normal JSON by registering a Date marshaller in Bootstrap:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
    String fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    return it.format(fmt)
}
```

However, this has no effect on domain class Dates sent out via JsonView.  I have tried to implement some global means of changing the Jackson Date serializer but so far to no avail.  How do I do this?  Documentation and examples are conflicting and confusing.

My build config:

```
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json" 
compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.1.2"
```

Thx, J

Comment: "Documentation and examples are conflicting and confusing." If you can point out what exactly you mean here in a github issue to grails-views, then it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example is using the JSON converter API, which has nothing to do with JSON views.

To achieve what you're looking for, you either need to manage the views yourself:

```
model {
   Book book
}

json {
    published book.published.format(...)  
}
```

Or use the current release candidate of grails-views (RC1) currently and implement a converter, which is described here: http://views.grails.org/1.2.x/#_custom_converters

Edit: To set the default timezone in views 1.2.x, there are a couple configuration options you can use:

`grails.views.json.generator.timeZone: "EST"`

and

`grails.views.json.generator.dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

Comment: I understand that the code I showed has nothing to do with JSON views, but it does illustrate that the problem can be solved in general, at least for anything going through a JSON converter.  JSON views are a different matter.  I will look into the RC1 version and see if that is fruitful and report back.

Comment: No luck.  I have implemented a converted, simple enough, but where, in the grails war file, should JsonGenerator$Converter end up?  After seeing no effect I've plastered it all over the place where I think "src/main/resources/META-INF/services/grails.plugin.json.builder.JsonGenerator$Converter" should be, but the converter is never accessed.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't need a converter.  All I need to do is to change the timeZone which defaults to "GMT" in JsonViewGeneratorConfiguration.  Can this be overridden by config?

Comment: Great!  Used the config for timeZone and I'm all set.  To avoid adjustments +- 1 hour the tz should be "America/New_York".